# How to create a webhook listener in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-runbook

I want to create a webhook listener in AWS to receive data from Azure.
I've created a webhook from Azure Runbook with my data from Sql Server

```
$SQLServerCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SqlCred"
$SQL_Server_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "SqlServer"
$SQL_DB_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "Database"

$Query = "select Calculated from dbo.Testings"
$Results = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQL_Server_Name" -Database "$SQL_DB_Name" -Credential $SQLServerCred -Query "$Query" -QueryTimeout 420

Write-Output $Results
```

With the webhook URL, I don't know how to forward it to AWS.
I know it can somehow be done by Lambda, but I didn't find any tutorial except forwarding to github or slack.
I'm hoping someone could give me a link to learn or some sample code that could guide me through it. Many Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "webhook listener in AWS"? I'm not familiar with that terminology on AWS. Can you describe what you are you wanting AWS to do when it receives something? We can then try to recommend an appropriate AWS service. (Please add details to your Question, rather than adding it as a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an API gateway to expose an HTTP API. API gateway can be used to trigger the lambda function and then using the lambda function you can perform the required task. You can also try integrating with AWS services directly instead of using the lambda function.

The simple steps to follow are

1. Create an IAM role that gives respective access to your API gateway
2. Create an API Gateway and configure it
3. Use required integration

AWS Document

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

An example for uploading data to S3 via Webhook

[API Gateway configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gClGG.png)